# What is causing the Execution plan difference between Azure SQL and SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am running a same query on a same copy of the database on a `Azure SQL (Tier S3) and SQL Server (12.0).` The execution plan differs and the performance on Azure SQL seems worse. The DB is an exact copy and includes the same Indexes. When observing the execution plan, the `Estimated Subtree Cost on SQL Server is 0.325 while on Azure SQL it is 1.431`. The largest percentage of the execution time is taken by a clustered index on one of the tables. The relative proportion that this part of query takes to execute differs between `Azure SQL (84%) and SQL Server (52%)`.

**Now my ask is :**
Should I be concerned about the performance of the query on Azure SQL?

If you think the difference in the execution plans is a concern, could you please advise if you have any ideas how to diagnose further or find a way to improve the Azure SQL query? If there is any more info I can provide, please let me know.

**Edit:**
SQL Server Execution plan:

[SQL Server XML file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48296214/sql_server.sqlplan)

[image]

[image]

Azure SQL Execution plan:

[Azure SQL XML file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48296214/sql_azure.sqlplan)

[image]

[image]

Comment: One of the  Important thing Optimizer considers while building an execution plan is Statistics.check whether you statistics are up to date.You can check this by seeing estimated vs actual rows.

Comment: Further post the plans if you see  stats are fine along with onprem server details like cpu,ram..

Comment: please post xml plan or share alink if it is huge

Comment: Thank you for a comment @TheGameiswar, I have edited the post. I have also updated statistics on SQL Server. Now the number of Estimated rows match between the Azure SQL and SQL Server, as well as the Actual between the two server. The only difference is in the Nested Loops node of the execution plan that can be seen on a screenshot.

Comment: Will get a link for XML plan.

Comment: images  are blocked in my office domain,so i cant say much

Comment: I have added the links

Comment: i got some errors while loading plan,could you please update your quesiton with actual ask you are having now and any performance differences?

Comment: I have updated the files behind the links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plan is same  in both the instances.Total plan cost always rounds upto 100%.So you may see one operator having high cost compared to another,but all summing upto 100%.

I am not saying keylookups are bad,but those are Random reads .From your plan i could see a single table was accessed twice (seek and lookup).So i recommend adding altering  below index after testing

This index `[IX_InstantMessageThreadAccesses_ProfileId]` should have one more key column( archived) and include this column  (kastreadon).By this way you will be to avoid nearly 44% of total query cost and it will result SQL in choosing a new plan.

Further i could see your statistics are not to update.I recommend doing an update stats for all the tables with fullscan(this may cause huge I/O activity if the tables are very big)...

```
UPDATE STATISTICS <<tablename>> WITH FULLSCAN
```

Update question if you have any questions further with steps done now and any diefferences you are seeing

Comment: Good call with the index. The plan has changed and the Estimated Subtree Cost has improved. Thanks for taking a time to answer.